# Resize text, but only if there's not enough room

Tags: html, font-size

I am creating a chart that shows keyboard commands overlaid on top of an image of a keyboard. I would like the text to shrink to the size of the container if it is too long to fit inside a key, but remain the default size otherwise. How would I accomplish this in HTML? The solutions I've seen seem to *always* alter the text size, versus *only* when the container is too small. Thanks.

Here's an example of what the result might look like:

[image]

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I think you are going to have to look at using javacript to achieve this,

Comment: You may have to resort using Javascript.

Comment: Does it make a difference if I always know beforehand what the dimensions of the container will be? (The sizes of the keyboard keys are known.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like word-wrap or overflow-wrap or adding a variable with css(i.e: a font-size that fits your needs) and only change it when a media queries (that you established) returns true;

**Media Queries explanation**:

Let's say I established this variable

```
:root {
  --font-size: 16px;
  /* this is your regular font size that you will use in your entire document */
}
```

So in a given screen size like so:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait) { 
   :root {
     --font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

You just change the value of the variable and it will change where ever you used that specific variable

*If you don't know how this works you can use this css variables like this*

```
.someClass {
  font-size: var(--font-size); */ and that's it  :) */
  /* You can also make calculations like this */
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size) - 40%);
}
```

Reference:

overflow-wrap: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

word-wrap: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

css variables: https://www.madebymike.com.au/writing/using-css-variables/

media queries: https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/media-queries-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Could you elaborate about the media queries? I've only used them to push different CSS depending on the size of the browser window. I'm not sure what other parameters can be queried.

Comment: @posfan12 improved answer

Comment: Yes, but I don't care about screen size (device width). I will display the same content regardless of screen size.

Comment: I have heard of it. It is not a finalized/official specification yet, correct? Browser support might be an issue.

Comment: @posfan12 https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox there is globally a 93.61% of browser support and partially 3.69% (browsers that require prefixes: -moz.. etc) a total of 97.3% so I think it really has a good support. If you're going to wait until 100% support them you may never use flexbox haha

Comment: How would I use flexbox to solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I had tried myself a solution with workarounds using flexbox but I can't replicate exactly what you're asking for, you may have to use javascript ... Sorry mate @posfan12